# Blowfish encryption / decryption with result saving (Qt - qblowfish)

Tags: qt, encryption, blowfish

How can I restore a cipher text that I've got from a succesful encryption with blowfish, when i save it in the meantime?

`secretKey` is the hash value of a keyword.

```
QString clearText(textBrowser->toHtml());

QBlowfish bf(secretKey);
bf.setPaddingEnabled(true);
QByteArray encryptedBa = bf.encrypted(clearText.toUtf8());

  // I want to save the encrypted text in a file to store it.
  // Here I am "emulating" this intent:
  // I am saving with flushing an outStream, I convert it to QString before:
QString test_SavedText(encryptedBa); //This value gets saved
QString cryptedText(test_SavedText); //"Read the stored file"

QByteArray decryptedBa = bf.decrypted(cryptedText.toUtf8());
```

`encryptedBa` is working. If I directly insert this into my `decrypted`-call, it is getting decrypted.
But when I call the decryption with my `cryptedText.toUtf8()`, it does not work.

Some debugging showed: The QString needs padding. So okay, in the decryption-method I added padding to its `QByteArray` (exactly the way it goes for encryption). But still my `decryptedBa`-output is empty. And still I don't understand why my QString needs padding - isn't it made from the QByteArray, that already includes padding?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is time since you asked the question, but as I've just stumbled on it, you don't want to use .toUtf8() on the encrypted data, but instead, on the result *after* decryption

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
QString enc(QString data) {
    QBlowfish bf(QString("This is The key").toUtf8());
    bf.setPaddingEnabled(true);
    QByteArray cipherText = bf.encrypted(data.toUtf8());
    return QString(cipherText.toHex());
}

QString dec(QString enc_data) {
    QBlowfish bf(QString("This is The key").toUtf8());
    bf.setPaddingEnabled(true); 
    QByteArray decryptedBa = bf.decrypted(QByteArray::fromHex(enc_data.toUtf8()));
    return QString::fromUtf8(decryptedBa.constData(), decryptedBa.size());
}
```